# Private Vector not being seen in class

Tags: c++

I am having an issue where a private vector declaration in my class "car" is not being recognized in it's own implementation file.  The other two private variables "model" and "cost" seem to be interpreted correctly by the compiler.  What am I doing wrong here?

The code below is still in progress so it is not complete.

Here is the compiler message:

```
.\car.cc: In member function 'void car::addPart(option)':
.\car.cc:18:2: error: 'parts' was not declared in this scope
   18 |  parts.push_back(input);
      |  ^~~~~
.\car.cc: In member function 'void car::displayInformation()':
.\car.cc:34:37: error: 'parts' was not declared in this scope
   34 |  for (vector<option>::iterator it = parts.begin(); it != parts.end(); ++it) {
      |                                     ^~~~~
```

Header File:

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include "library.h"

class car {

public:

    ///Default constructor
    car() {
        model = 'N';
        cost = 0;
    }

    /**
    * setmodel - a mutator for the car model
    * @param input - the character the model will be set to.  Expects 'E', 'L', or 'X'
    */
    void setModel(char input) { model = input; }
    /** getModel - an accessor for the car model
    *  @return - the car model
    */
    char getModel() { return model; }

    /**
    * setCost - a mutator for the car cost
    * @param value - the cost the car will be set to
    */
    void setCost(double value) { cost = value; }
    /** getCost - an accessor for the car cost
    *  @return - the car cost
    */
    double getCost() { return cost; }

    /**
    *  Function:   calculateCost
    *              reads through the parts list and adds up the current cost of the car
    */
    void calculateCost();

    /**
    *  Function:   addPart
    *              add the option passed in to the part list
     *
    *  @param input - the option to be added
    */
    void addPart(option input);

    /**
    *  Function:   removePart
    *              Remove the part with the index passed in from the list.  This will shuffle the later
    *              indexed parts to the left in index.
    *
    *  @param index - the endex of the part to be removed
    */
    void removePart(int index);

    /**
     *  Function:   restart
     *              Resets all of the information about the car.  This function is called when the user
     *              wants to start over with their choices.
     */
    void restart();

    /**
     *  Function:   displayInformation
     *              Outputs the car information to the user
     */
    void displayInformation();

private:

    vector<option> parts;   ///This will store the list of parts (options) the user has selected for the car
    char model;             ///This will store the model of the car
    double cost;            ///This will store the current cost of the car

};

#endif
```

Implementation:

```
#include "library.h"

using namespace std;

void car::calculateCost() {

}

void car::addPart(option input) {

    parts.push_back(input);

}

void car::removePart(int index) {

}

void car::restart() {

}

void car::displayInformation() {

    cout << "Model: " << model << ", $" << cost << ", Options: ";

    for (vector<option>::iterator it = parts.begin(); it != parts.end(); ++it) {

        cout << *it.getName();

        vector<option>::iterator comma_test = it;
        ++comma_test;
        if (comma_test != parts.end()) {
            cout << ", ";
        }

    }

}
```

Library Header:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "option.h"
#include "car.h"

#endif
```

Comment: Is this the very first error that appears in the compiler's logs? There should definitely be at least another one beforehand that would point directly at the specific error in the code.

Comment: That actually is the first error.

Comment: unless you have a top-level `using namespace std;` inside of 'option.h' (which there really shouldn't be), your compiler should be complaining that `vector does not name a type` at the point where `parts` is declared.

Comment: fwiw, the practice of saving the 5 `std::` char in front of type names by adding a `using namespace std` **will** sooner or later cost you hours of headache.

Comment: Well that is very interesting.  I did just catch the lack of std:: (I feel dumb now), but that doesn't change the compiler error at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `option.h` also `#include "library.h"`? Circular includes are nothing but trouble, and will cause a miriad of weird looking bugs. car.h including library.h "works" just barely because car.h is the very last include.

Comment: It does.  I figured a good approach was to have #ifndef flags on each header file and have everything include the library header file.  Is that not a good idea?

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of having a single `library.h` file that tries to include everything, try to keep your includes as close to the file that uses them as possible. Often that means a source `.cc` file, but sometimes it means a header `.h` file. This will tend to make maintenance a lot easier.

Comment: The header guards are good, but they don't magically make circular includes work. They only guard against the same header being included multiple times, but the header graphs must remain a DAG. (baring rare exotic setups)

Comment: *Is that not a good idea?*  No, that's a terrible idea.  Unless you work for my competitor's company, in which case it's a great idea, carry on!

Comment: @spectras you make a good point.  But you can use `using std::vector` and save those 5 characters in a much safer fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was that I had circular header file dependencies.  I was also being naughty and had "using namespace std."  I guess using a the library header file was not as clever as I originally thought.  Thanks all for the help!